# How to delay promise execute after defer is resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise

I used angular `$q` to create a defer object like this:

```
var defer = $q.defer();
var promise = defer.promise;

setTimeout(function(defer){
    defer.resolve("nothing");
},2000,defer);

promise.then(function(){
    //code here
});
```

So the code in promise will delay 2 seconds, but **I want to know how to delay code execution after defer is resolved**, so that I can delay code execution like this:

```
promise.delay(1000);
```

when I get a promise from $http.post()

```
var promise = $http.post()...;
promise.then(function(){
     // code 
});
```

how to delay that code execute , since promise is resolved.

Comment: What do you mean by "after defer is resolved"? Which *defer* are you referring to?

Comment: @kazenorin  var defer = $q.defer(); This defer ,and in settimeout the defer  passed from out.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `setTimeout`, which also has the benefit of already returning a promise.

To start the delay only after the initial promise is resolved, just put it inside a `then` callback:

```
promise.then(function(){
    return $timeout(2000)
}).then(function(){
    //code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks. it works well.  when I write like this " var promise1 = promise.then(function(){
    return $timeout(2000)
});  return promise1;"

Comment: You may want to pass on the data from the first promise so the last `.then()` can have access to the value from the first promise.

Comment: @jfriend00: That appears to be ugly in angular though: `promise.then(x => $timeout(()=>x, 2000))`

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code in your revolved block.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   //Code goes here.
},delayTime);
```

delayTime is the milliseconds of the delay.

Comment: Thank you. but not my want.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following:

```
var result = $q.defer();

$timeout(function() {
    result.resolve('nothing');
}, 2000);

return result.promise;
```

and then later wherever you need it

```
result.then(function(result) {
    // if you need to delay the result handling then you need another $timeout call here like so:
    $timeout(function() {
        // do something with result
        $scope.result = result;
    }, 1000);
});
```

**EDIT**: Included another $timeout call in order to delay handling of resolved promise

Comment: now I just do like you said. but my question is how can I change delay time of result.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you need, but I will update my answer